# How to orderly move elements in an array adding a new element

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently trying to write code to have a list stored in an array, so new elements are added in the first null location, but if none of them are null, it should shift all elements one to the left, deleting the first one, and add the new one in the end. But I'm not able to make it work.

```
public void add(Class c) { 
    if (c!=null) {
       for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
         if (array[i] == null) {
            array[i] = c;
            break;
         }
         if (array[array.length-1] != null) {
            for (int j=0; j<array.length-1; j++) {
                 array[j] = array[j+1];
            }
            array[array.length-1] = c;
         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your indentation is obscuring the meaning of the code, but the second for-loop is inside the first, which hopefully was not what you intended.

Comment: Replace break with return in the first loop to start with since you are done if you find an empty spot

Comment: Like Joakim said use return; instead of break; and take second for loop outside of first for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Write exactly what you have said in your question:

> so new elements are added in the first null location,

So create a loop and find that position:

```java
public void add(Class c) { 
    if (c != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == null) {
                array[i] = c;
                return; // nothing to be done, just exit
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

> but if none of them are null, it should shift all elements one to the
> left, deleting the first one, and add the new one in the end.

```java
public void add(Class c) { 
    if (c != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == null) {
                array[i] = c;
                return; // nothing to be done, just exit
            }
        }

        // If we reach this part, there is no null in the array.
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
        }
        array[array.length - 1] = c;
    }
}
```

IMO you can improve readability of your code by extracting the following method:

```java
public boolean add_to_free_position(Class c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == null) {
            array[i] = c;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and adapting your code accordingly:

```java
public void add(Class c) { 
    if (c != null && !add_to_free_position(c)) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
            array[j] = array[j+1];
        }
        array[array.length-1] = c;
    }
}
```